# What very large functional language projects are freely available?

Tags: open-source, scala, functional-programming, clojure

To begin with, I'm virtually sold on the 'whole functional language thing'.  It occurs to me that, for years, I've been doing mostly functional-style programming in Java.  But I'm a bit loss as to how to start a large functional app.  I'd like to see the source and build structure of a large project (OSS or whatever) so that I can see how modularity is best handled in such an environment.

The context of my question is that I want to start a large JVM project and I'm currently thinking of choosing a Java/Groovy mix or a Scala/Groovy mix.  I don't want to go with the Scala/Groovy mix unless I'm going in the functional direction because I don't like Scala for OO programming (a completely different topic).  This means avoiding stuff like DI frameworks, AspectJ, etc.  (I know I can emulate/accomplish/approve on these things with functional programming... but that's not relevant here.)  I'm worried that the lack of very large publicly visible projects using these languages is due to the common argument that they really are poor for large projects, which would be a real shame...

So I ask, what large fp projects (lets say 20K+ lines) do you follow?  I'd be most happy to hear of any that run in a language on the JVM.  Especially if you feel they handle modularity in a good way.

Comment: Some interesting projects have been listed for Erlang, Haskell and Lisp (no Scala or Clojure... maybe thats a sign). I really like Wings 3D. But none of the projects seem to exhibit much modularity (except for Emacs which, it has been mentioned, is quite imperatively written... as I recall from writing plugins over a decade ago).  I didn't use the term 'enterprise' because its generally a useless term but I'm really seeking a project that builds on other non-core or 'standard library' type code.  Something akin in size and cross-cutting utility to the Spring Framework or Hibernate or OSGI...

Comment: A see a "sign" for Clojure: http://flightcaster.com/team

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm trying to grok Erlang these days, which Scala is influenced by. I like to study the source code of [yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/), which is a high-performance http server, and [Wings 3D](http://www.wings3d.com/), a subdivision modeler. Very educational, the best way to learn a new language is to read it.

Answer (score 7):

The darcs distributed version control system is pure haskell, i.e. pure and lazy fp. By lines of code this might not seem to be a large project, but keep in mind that haskell syntax is very dense.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs has lots of Lisp in it, but it is written in a very imperative style. GHC is a large project written in Haskell, and of course the OCaml compiler, etc., are written in OCaml.

Comment: Mind you, there's a difference between Lisps. The language inside Emacs is Emacs-lisp. Common Lisp is a whole different language, which was even cast as an ANSI standard.

Answer (score 3):

There are two big open source efforts in Scala that I know of: [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) and [ESME](http://blog.esme.us/) ([Apache Incubator](http://incubator.apache.org/esme/#overview)).

Though it seems Google-related new language [Noop](http://code.google.com/p/noop/) is written in Scala so far. That's likely to change when Noop becomes stable enough to compile itself.

Answer (score 3):

[Xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) is a window manager written in Haskell, they have a very detailed [tutorial](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/xmonad_development_tutorial) for writing extensions.

Comment: The tutorial does not cover any actual programming; only using Darcs and Haddock.

Comment: my bad here are the developer docs http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Doc-Developing.html

Comment: Last I looked, XMonad was only 3kLOC.

Comment: But a 3k functional project compares to 20k+ imperative projects :)

Comment: @progo: I agree but he asked for 20k+ FP projects. I think the only thing you'll get for Haskell (apart from GHC itself) is Darcs, which is 25kLOC: http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2008/08/haskells-virginity.html

Comment: @Jon, oh right the OP mentioned a limit. My bad :)

Answer (score 3):

It is written in OCaml and therefore does not run on the JVM,
but Frama-C is a 200000+ lines project implementing
a static analysis framework for C, with a plug-in architecture.

Frama-C uses dynamic loading of native
code where available, but plug-ins can also always be loaded
dynamically as bytecode or linked statically if you are willing
to recompile the whole thing.

More information, including source code, at [http://frama-c.com/](http://frama-c.cea.fr/).
Considering the nature of your question, you might also appreciate
[this article at ICFP 09](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1596550.1596591)

Answer (score 3):

Scala/Lift :
Novell Vibe : http://vibe.novell.com/
Author: twitter.com/djspiewak

Clojure : 
Clj/Sys - Machine Learning Network
Author: twitter.com/bradfordcross

Clojure
Runa Predictive Mining Framework for Cart Abandonment
Author: Amit Rathore (Clojure in Action)

Answer (score 2):

I know large portions of [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) and basically all of [Maxima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_(software)) are written in Lisp. These don't run in the JVM, but they are the top examples I can think of for large, well established, and widely used and appreciated applications written in a functional language.

Comment: Emacs is not written in a functional style.

Answer (score 2):

Citrix released the Xen API toolstack as open source software [here](http://xenbits.xen.org/xapi/xen-api.hg?file/b810043e9ab0/ocaml/) last year. IIRC, that is hundreds of thousands of lines of OCaml code that was developed by 18 developers from 2006 to 2010.

According to [this page](http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2008/08/haskells-virginity.html):

- The [MLDonkey](http://mldonkey.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) peer-to-peer client is 171kLOC of OCaml code.
- [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) is 24kLOC of OCaml code.
- [FFTW](http://fftw.org) is 14kLOC of OCaml code.
- [Hevea](http://hevea.inria.fr/) is 12kLOC of OCaml code.
- [Darcs](http://darcs.net/) is 25kLOC of Haskell code.

> I'm worried that the lack of very large publicly visible projects using these languages is due to the common argument that they really are poor for large projects, which would be a real shame...

On the contrary, we found OCaml to be much *better* for large projects that mainstream languages like Java or C# where the inability to express productive high-level aspects of the code leads to extensive cut-and-paste and maintenance problems. In fact, I am currently challenged with rewriting a million lines of C++ in [F#](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/products/fsharp_for_technical_computing/?so) precisely because maintenance has become prohibitively expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Koders, the [Open source Code Search engine](http://koders.com/) might be of help as it allows you to search in programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

There are some very big and old projects writen in Lisp:
http://www.pchristensen.com/blog/lisp-companies/